# How to ignore a parameter in stored procedure if its value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure in which I have to join 10 tables and use `WHERE` condition to filter the records based on the parameters passed in the stored procedure. For example:

```
create procedure proc1
    @var1 varchar(100) = null,
    @var2 varchar(100) = null,
    @var3 varchar(100) = null,
    @var4 varchar(100) = null,
    ........   
    @var10 varchar(100) = null
as
begin
    insert into #a
    select * from
    (
        select * from 
            tab1 as a
            inner join tab2 as b on a.rollnumber = b.rollnumber
            inner join tab3 as c on c.city = b.city
            ........
            inner join tab10 as j on J.id = i.id
        where 
            a.id = isnull(@var1,a.id) and 
            b.id = isnull(@var2,b.id) and 
            c.id = isnull(@var3,c.id) and 
            ...........
            J.id = isnull(@var10,j.id)
    ) as abc

    if (select count(*) from #a) < 10 
    begin
        select * from #a
    end
    else 
    begin
        print 'Cannot display the records as count is more than 10'
    end
end
```

Above stored procedure is working fine, but it is slow because there are 10 conditions in the `WHERE` clause. What I want is to skip the condition if some parameters are not supplied to the stored procedure. For example, if only 3 parameters are passed to the stored procedure, then `WHERE` clause should skip the rest of the parameters from the `WHERE` clause. This will make the procedure more efficient. So, if `@var1` is not passed, all the values of `a.id` should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good article [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog. He explains several approaches that could be used and compares building dynamic SQL as @lad2025 suggested and using `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`.

I personally use [`OPTION(RECOMPILE)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) in these queries. You use SQL Server 2008, so this option is a good choice. If you do go via the dynamic SQL route, make sure to read his another article [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

So, your procedure becomes something like this:

```
create procedure proc1
    @var1 varchar(100) = null,
    @var2 varchar(100) = null,
    @var3 varchar(100) = null,
    @var4 varchar(100) = null,
    ........   
    @var10 varchar(100) = null
as
begin
    insert into #a
    select * from
    (
        select * 
        from
            tab1 as a
            inner join tab2 as b on a.rollnumber = b.rollnumber
            inner join tab3 as c on c.city = b.city
            ........
            inner join tab10 as j on J.id = i.id
        where 
            (a.id = @var1 OR @var1 IS NULL)
            and (b.id = @var2 OR @var2 IS NULL)
            and (c.id = @var3 OR @var3 IS NULL)
            ...........
            and (J.id = @var10 OR @var10 IS NULL)
    ) as abc
    OPTION(RECOMPILE);

    if (select count(*) from #a) < 10 
    begin
        select * from #a
    end
    else 
    begin
        print 'Cannot display the records as count is more than 10'
    end
end
```

By the way, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve by checking the `count()`, but maybe all you need is simple `TOP(10)` to return at most 10 first rows. Make sure to add `ORDER BY` clause if you do use `TOP` to return results consistently. If you didn't know, you can have another parameter of your procedure to indicate the maximum number of rows to return and use it in `TOP(@ParamMaxRowCount)`. It is not common to have a stored procedure that sometimes returns result set and sometimes only prints a message.

Answer (score 0):

Let's play with Dynamic - SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_procedure]
     @var1 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @var2 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @var3 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @var4 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     /* ........  */ 
     @var10 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @debug INT         = 0
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
    @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX),                                
    @paramlist  NVARCHAR(4000),                              
    @nl         CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);


/* Main query here */
SELECT @sql = 
   'SELECT * 
    FROM tab1 AS a
    INNER JOIN tab2 AS b
      ON a.rollnumber = b.rollnumber
    INNER JOIN tab3 AS c
      ON c.city = b.city
    /* ........ and so on */
    INNER JOIN tab10 AS j
      ON J.id = i.id
    WHERE 1 = 1 ' + @nl;

IF @var1 IS NOT NULL                                            
    SELECT @sql += ' AND a.id = @var1' + @nl;  

IF @var2 IS NOT NULL                                            
    SELECT @sql += ' AND b.id = @var2' + @nl;  

/* ... */

IF @var10 IS NOT NULL                                            
    SELECT @sql += ' AND j.id = @var10' + @nl;

/* If sorting needed just add it;
SELECT @sql += ORDER BY a.id;
*/

IF @debug = 1
    PRINT @sql;


SELECT @paramlist = 
      '@var1     VARCHAR(100),   
       @var2     VARCHAR(100),
       /* ... */
       @var10     VARCHAR(100)';

/*CREATE TABLE #temp definition here */

INSERT INTO #temp(col1, col2, ...)
EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
           @sql,
           @paramlist,
           @var1,
           @var2,
           /* ... */
           @var10;

IF @@ROWCOUNT < 10 
THEN
    SELECT *       /* Use column names */
    FROM #temp;
ELSE
    PRINT 'Cannot display the records as count is more than 10';
END
```

Usage as any normal stored procedure + debug if want to see query:

```
 EXEC [dbo].[my_procedure]
            @var1 = 'AAA'
           ,@var2 = 'BBB'
           ,@debug = 1;
```

- Formatting is everything, especially when Dynamic-SQL is used.
- Instead of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp` use `@@ROWCOUNT`;
- Printing from SP is not good practice, better to return some value to indicate it in OUT parameter.
- If you don't like `WHERE 1 = 1` you can first check if all arguments are NULLs and skip it.
- You don't need to use Dynamic SQL at all, just use `IF THEN ELSE IF THEN ELSE IF ... ELSE` and do massive duplication of hard to maintain code (if Line Of Code is metric used to measure your productivity it can be useful)

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` condition should use the `CASE` statement:

```
CASE WHEN @val IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE SellCashID END = CASE WHEN @val IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE @SellCashID END
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to give the parameters which are being used.

If only value for Var1 needs to be passed.

```
proc1 @Var1 = Var1Value
```

If the value for Var6 needs to be passed.

```
Proc1 @Var6 = Var6Value
```

Please use case in this like

```
 where case @var1 when null then 1 else  a.id end =  case @var1 when null then 1 else  @var1 end
```

Hope this will help you
Thanks

Comment: This will not help. All conditions in the where clause will still be used