# why non clustered index is used instead of clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure. If I use where (@detailId is null or SalesOrderDetailID = @detailId) then non clustered index is used, but if I change the where clause to SalesOrderDetailID = @detailId then clusted index is used.

Check the below stored procedure.The primary key is combination of columns - (SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetail).

```
alter procedure samproc

@detailId int = null

with recompile
as
begin

select SalesOrderID 
from sales.SalesOrderDetail 
where  (@detailId is null or SalesOrderDetailID = @detailId)

end
go

exec dbo.samproc @detailId = 1
```

Question - why clustered index is not used when I use or condition in the where clause. I need to use or because want to skip the where condition if parameter is not passed.I also used

```
where isnull(@detailId,SalesOrderDetailID)
```

but in real scenario's I have 10 parameters and this can be expensive because index of columns inside isnull function will not be used and secondly isnull causes table scan.  That is the reason why I used

```
where  (@detailId is null or SalesOrderDetailID = @detailId)
```

Can someone tell me how to avoid non clustered index and use clustered index.

Comment: If you feel a certain index provides better performance than what SQL Server chooses, you can force it to use that index.

Comment: `SalesOrderDetailID = isnull(@detailId,SalesOrderDetailID)` IS NOT SARGable "SQL Server cannot use an
index seek when you apply a function to a column"

Answer (score 1):

Index usage with `or` is troublesome.  Your best bet is to construct a dynamic SQL statement and execute that:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
select SalesOrderID 
from sales.SalesOrderDetail 
where 1=1 ';

if (@detailId is not null)
begin
    @sql := @sql + 'SalesOrderDetailID = ' + cast(@detailId as varchar(255));
end;

exec sp_execute_sql @sql;
```

Note:  you should probably do this with parameters . . .

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
select SalesOrderID 
from sales.SalesOrderDetail 
where 1 = 1 ';

if (@detailId is not null)
begin
    @sql := @sql + 'and SalesOrderDetailID = @detailid';
end;

exec sp_execute_sql @sql, '@detailid int', @detailid = @detailid
```

The result will be a simpler statement that can better take advantage of indexes.

Comment: But how are you going to give if (@detailId is not null) condition when there are 10 parameters. How many nestede ifs will you take in that case..

Comment: @sam Did you read answers to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153904/how-to-ignore-a-parameter-in-stored-procedure-if-its-value-is-null)?

Comment: @lad2025 Yes you are using the condition IF for only one parameter; Can you tell me  what will happen in case var1 is not null and var2 is null. In which of your if condition will this case come in. Let me tell you , in this case none of your if conditions will be executed. Because you should have used -IF var1 IS NOT NULL  and var2 is null

Comment: @sam try my solution, use @debug=1 see query and we can talk futher.

Comment: @sam . . . This query appends the conditions one-by-one to the `where` clause, if the condition is needed.